# can i make a call to http://api.example.com from https://example.com?

Tags: php, ajax, django, ssl

I am using django as backend API and ajax for making api call.my main site runs on https but the api on http . i am unable to make api calls from ssl cert loaded onto ngnix.

**is it possible to make ajax calls from https to http ?**

any leads will be appreciated ?

thnks in advance ..!!

Comment: Have you tried Curl to solve this? You could make an ajax call to the same server which gets the information from the http site through Curl. You could create a wrapper for the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser will stop this and/or give an insecure warning and a padlock symbol for your HTTPS connection.

HTTPS indicates the site is secure, which gives certain guarantees to the visitor - namely that the site is for the given domain (authentication), that it's not been intercepted and changed (integrity) and that no one else is able to listen in to your messages to and from the server (confidentiality).

When you add an insecure resource like an api call, those guarantees are no longer there and so the browser will give a "insecure" warning, typically with a yellow warning padlock (instead of green) and/or a pop up.

Browsers used to differentiate between inactive content (e.g. images) - which were seen as less of a risk and so allowed, and active content (e.g. JavaScript) - which were potentially dangerous and so not allowed, however don't think they do any more. Even if they did Ajax XHR calls are definitely in the latter category.

Best option is to [proxy pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) the request through your main site domain through Nginx (e.g. forward requests to https://example.com/api from Nginx to your api using Nginx config).

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between HTTP and HTTPS is the SSL security part, if your server is able to handle HTTPS requests they will be send through to the API just like any other HTTP request, it's only the actual data communication from the client socket to the server socket that is affected, once the data is received it's back in plain text (or it's original format) again.

Comment: As long as that server has SSL support and the certificates are setup properly there's no reason why it shouldn't work. Of-course you'd need either a wildcard certificate or two seperate SSL certificates to get them to work but my point still applies.

Comment: He wants to make a call from an https to http. This will not be allowed. I gather you're saying upgrade the api to https? If so I agree that will work but that's not what was asked nor made clear in your answer nor why you have to do this.